# Is there any distinction between using function or pointer to function notation?

Tags: c, function-pointers, c11, function-prototypes, function-parameter

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f() {}
void g1(void fun(void)) { printf("%p\n", &fun); }
void g2(void (*fun)(void)) { printf("%p\n", fun); }

int main(void) {
    g1(f);
    g2(&f);
    printf("%p\n", &f);
    return 0;
}
```

As C11 does not have lambda expressions, there is no way a literal function could be passed as parameter to `g1` or `g2`, so in a way, these two functions do the same thing(you must define the parameters first); I'm reading a book right now that says that

> The fact that technically this function (`f`) is passed on as a function
>   pointer (to `g1`) is usually of minor interest, [...]

So, what I understand is that the writer is saying that both semantically are equivalent.

But the addresses that get printed when calling `g1` and `g2` are different, where `g2` outputs the real address of `f`. This means that `g1` makes a copy of `f`, meaning that `f` is passed by value. Is the book wrong or am I? I don't think the book is wrong, but the addresses are different and certainly it matters which one you choose. And if there are any distinctions, which one should be prefered in what scenario?

Comment: Just so you know, I compiled this with `-Wall  -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic` and got three warnings.

Comment: Yes, all format-mismatch-warnings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a80c6b7a990222d9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very wrong.

Whenever you think you pass a function to a function, you are actually passing a pointer to it.
Whenever a function Looks like it has a function-parameter, it actually has a function-pointer-parameter.

Now, in one of your functions you print the value of a pointer to the argument, in the other the argument. Aside from the fact that `%p` is for `void*` not for other data-pointers and especially not for function-pointers, which means you have Undefined Behavior, there is every reason to expect them to be different, especially on an architecture with a shared address space for data and instructions.

Comment: Do you mean *without* a shared address space?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: If you have a shared address space, it's somewhat difficult to have a modifiable stack and static instructions overlapping. If you don't have one shared address space, data:pointer and code:pointer (with pointer being identical) would be independent.

Answer (score 3):

> But the addresses that get printed when calling `g1` and `g2` are different, where `g2` outputs the real address of `f`. This means that `g1` makes a copy of `f`, meaning that `f` is passed by value.

You are incorrect. In both `g1` and `g2`, the variable `fun` is a function pointer, not a function. Using `&fun` in `g1` gives the address (on the stack) where the function pointer is stored -- not the actual address of the function.

Functions are not values in C or C++. They cannot be copied, and they cannot be passed by value.